# WiFi stops working when connected to Bluetooth box

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, huawei

When I connect my Android 6 Huawei to my bluetooth box and play music my wifi decides to kill itself, while it is still on and connected.

Comment: Wifi and Bluetooth usually use the same frequency range. Therefore it is not unusual that the one can affect the other.

Comment: My phone uses 2.4Ghz, I don't know what my box uses, but can I change the freq. of the box?

Comment: Bluetooth uses by definition the 2.4GHz range. Usually devices are optimized for minimal side effected when using both Bluetooth and Wifi. For an unknown reason on your device the situation seems to be different.